# How can I properly add a eslint config to NuxtJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, nuxt.js, eslint-config-airbnb

So I just freshly installed a new Nuxt app and have this config in my `.eslintrc.js`:

```
extends: [
  '@nuxtjs',
  'plugin:prettier/recommended'
]
```

I want to use the airbnb eslint rules so I installed `eslint-config-airbnb`.

If I add `airbnb` in my rules,

```
extends: [
  '@nuxtjs',
  'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  'airbnb'
]
```

Will this affect `@nuxtjs`?